# How can I tell if wheat flour is vegan?

Tags: veganism, is-it-vegan

[In another answer](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/245/70), I learned that some flour is not vegan because it may have been bleached with bone char.

When I'm shopping, **what do I need to look for to ensure I'm getting vegan flour?**

Comment: Also, watch out for L-Cysteine (E920), which is also often used. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cysteine#Dietary_restrictions)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you happen to live in a place that demands trace chemicals to be described in the label, look for known inorganic oxidants:

- Bromates or Iodates

[image]

- Peroxides (calcium, magnesium, etc) and/or azodicarbonamide (also azo[bis]formamide)

http://seaystanford.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Screen-Shot-2013-07-28-at-3.57.44-PM.png

- Chlorine [dioxide|oxide] (ClO<sub>2</sub>) or Nitrogen dioxide (NO<sub>2</sub>)

> I couldn't find a picture because they are not mandatorily listed.

The reason why those agents are guaranteed to point to vegan flour is simple: they react strongly with organic matter. Adding animal products to the process would make them less effective and increase overall production costs.

If none of those agents are listed in a bleached flour, then it is likely to have been bleached by bone char, or a reductant chemical such as L-cysteine/L-cystine (produced from animal hair and feathers).

There is, however, a widely used inorganic oxidant that does not need to be listed in the package: oxygen (or, sometimes, just air). Regular air will whiten flour just as well, it just takes a lot longer to reach the *right white*. Flour whitened by either air or O<sub>2</sub> are considered *unbleached* for legal purposes.

[image]

Alternatively, you can use non-whitened varieties of flour, such as whole wheat flour.

OBS: all of the above inorganic chemicals are known carcinogens, and, as such, might have been banned from your country.

Comment: I would be suspect of the riboflavin on that label too...

Comment: Do you happen to know if brown bread is vegan?

Comment: I can't find any resources online mentioning bleaching of flour with bone char can you refer me to some?

Comment: I recently contacted a mill and was told that bleaching of flour is illegal in the European Union and Canada.