# Is brown bread vegetarian and/or vegan?

Tags: veganism, is-it-vegan

A quick Google doesn't say anything. Reading at the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_bread) article it seems like it is but I am not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Brown" bread usually means a type of bread made either with whole wheat flour or a mixture of whole wheat flour and white wheat flour. Sometimes gluten free bread products are called "brown bread" too - these may be made with a mixture of flours.

Bread, "brown" or white, leavened or not, is usually vegan. The basic ingredients are

- flour (which will most likely, but [not certainly](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/249/how-can-i-tell-if-wheat-flour-is-vegan), be vegan)
- yeast (a unicellular microorganism significantly less complex than any plant)
- water
- sugar
- salt

But it may sometimes be enriched with butter or other dairy products or honey, or have a coating that contains egg. Vitamins and minerals, preservatives and other trace ingredients may also be added, so you will need to check the ingredients list and suitability labelling, or contact the maker if this information is not available.

Comment: Here: https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/249/how-can-i-tell-if-wheat-flour-is-vegan is claimed that some flour is not vegan therefore not all bread is vegan.

Comment: @PetarVasilev if you knew the answer why didn't you post it yourself? XD Added link to that question

Comment: I am asking about brown bread not normal bread. I thought there might be a difference.

Comment: @PetarVasilev brown bread is not a technical term, but in general it means some of the bran and germ of the wheat has not been removed from the flour, so, it's not automatically more or less vegan

Comment: Beware honey, if you care about honey...

Comment: I recently contacted a mill and was told that bleaching of flour is illegal in the European Union and Canada.