# Why does this vegan chocolate have cholesterol?

Tags: labeling, cholesterol

[image: Image of the chocolate box]

If I am not wrong, this chocolate is vegan. And I also know that vegan foods do not contain cholesterol.

So why does it say it has 1mg cholesterol?
Thank you.

Comment: this is an approximate number which comes from milk (read may contain ingredients)

Comment: Does it say it's vegan on the labeling, or are you assuming it's vegan based on ingredients?

Comment: Also, see: https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1516/are-foods-with-zero-cholesterol-always-vegan/1582#1582

Comment: It is most likely an error in typing up the nutrition facts. You need to contact the manufacturer to confirm this; you haven’t provided enough information here (eg. flavour, batch number) for somebody else to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: The only result for lindt chocolate of 125g and 52% I can find is https://www.lindtusa.com/dark-chocolate-swiss-thins-418467aa and this doesn't have cholesterol according to that website.

Answer (score 8):

There is some confusion online about the sources of cholesterol, which can come in dietary form through animal or dairy products, or can be made internally by one's own body, for example when processing trans fats:

[livekindly.co](https://www.livekindly.co/how-do-vegans-get-cholesterol/):

> Trans fat is added to processed foods through an industrial process where hydrogen is added to vegetable oil, which allows the oil to be solid at room temperature. On ingredients labels, it’s called “partially hydrogenated vegetable oil,” and it is used to give many packaged foods a longer shelf life.

Therefore, fully vegan food will never have cholesterol. Therefore, 1mg sounds like an error or a strange choice to round up from zero.